# Javascript show some content after stopping window load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing a chrome extension that stops page load for a specific website. The way I do that is my content script get's injected in the page and calls

```
window.stop()
```

This works as expected and I see a blank white web page. I now want to show a custom message on this blank white page, how do I do that.

This is what I have tried so far, after calling window.stop() I have this line:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%; z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>';
```

but it throws an error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

I checked the DOM and it does have body tag in it. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: It is probably better to use `webRequest` to redirect to a page in your extension than use a content script in that way.

Comment: Did not know about webRequest and it definitely looks interesting, can you please write a small piece of code demonstrating it's use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you block a site by injecting a content script at `document_start` and deciding there whether to block.

A better approach would be to cancel the initial request entirely, and redirect it to your own error page.

[`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) can do that:

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
      if(/* condition based on details */) {
        // The file might need to be in web_accessible_resources
        return {redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL("my_error.html")};
      }
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]},
    ["blocking"]
 );
```

Note: this will call your test code on every navigation request; this can potentially slow things down. If you have a specific list of sites, you may put them in the `urls` parameter of the filter to get better performance.

You will need host permissions covering the sites you want to block (or `"<all_urls>"` if you potentially need all of them), `"webRequest"` and `"webRequestBlocking"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use window.document.write().

You code will look like...

```
document.write("<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%; z-index:100;background:#000;'></div>")
```